# Java - NoSuchMethodException with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I get a `NoSuchMethodException` when executing:

```
operacionDTO.getClass().getMethod("setPrioridad").invoke(operacionDTO, 0);

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xxxx.api.service.dto.RegasificacionDTO.setPrioridad()
```

But class `RegasificacionDTO` does have a public method called `setPrioridad(int i)`, and if when debugging I call:

```
operacionDTO.getClass().getMethods()
```

Then I get an array of Method in which there is a `setPrioridad`. I've tried with some other similar methods and I get the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to include the parameter signature.

```
 operacionDTO.getClass().getMethod("setPrioridad", Integer.TYPE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Method `getMethod()` accepts method name and an varargs array of parameter types. In your case you should call `getMethod("setPrioridad", int.class)` and everything will work.

This is because in java (as in most object oriented languages) you can define several methods with the same name and different signatures, so the system distinguishes among them using given parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

```
 operacionDTO.getClass().getMethod("setPrioridad",new Class[]{Integer.TYPE or Integer.class}).invoke(operacionDTO, 0);
```