# Unable to find public method via getMethod()

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Supposedly this is not a new problem however I am having trouble finding the solution, because most answers to this refer to the method in question not being public.

#### Context

There is a package named `reflection`, where annotations as well as a `UITester` class are defined, the latter uses a class-annotation and a method-annotation. A different package named `gui` contains a class `MinimalUI` which then tests access to `UITester`, its methods and the respective annotation values. However I am running into a `NoSuchMethodException`.

#### Code

**FunctionAnnotation**

The annotation is used to lock/unlock methods.

```
package reflection;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;

@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Target( {ElementType.METHOD} )
public @interface FunctionAnnotation
{
    boolean locked();
}
```

**SampleAnnotation**

Simple annotation to set some basic class properties.

```
package reflection;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public

@interface SampleAnnotation
{
    String name();
    String value();
    boolean output(); 
}
```

**UITester**

This is the annotated class. The class declaration itself is annotated and so is one method of the class, so both annotations previously shown are used.

```
package reflection;

@SampleAnnotation( name = "default", value = "[MINIMAL UI ANNOTATION] Testing.", output = true )
public class UITester
{
    public UITester()
    {
        System.out.println( "[UI TESTER] Created." );
    }

    public void print( String value )
    {
        System.out.println( "[UI TESTER] Printing: " + value );
    }

    @FunctionAnnotation( locked = false )
    public void printIfAvailable( String value )
    {
         System.out.println( "[UI TESTER] Printing (available): " + value );
    }
}
```

**MinimalUI**

Finally there is a minimal UI class that implements the `Gui` interface, declared in the same package. I am posting just the relevant test method, because otherwise this sample will become a bit large. The following code is method `MinimalUI#testUI`. It needs to read the annotations set for `UITester` and behave in accordance with the results. The implementation is minimalistic and lacks safeguards, which is fine, because this is a sandbox project where I am testing patterns to be transferred to production. The code:

```
@Override
public void testUI()
{
    UITester tester = new UITester();
    Annotation annotation = UITester.class.getAnnotation( SampleAnnotation.class );

    if ( annotation instanceof SampleAnnotation )
    {
        String value = ( (SampleAnnotation) annotation ).value();

        tester.print( value );

        try
        {
            Method possiblyLockedMethod = UITester.class.getMethod( "printIfAvailable" );
            Annotation methodLockCheck = possiblyLockedMethod.getAnnotation( FunctionAnnotation.class );

            if ( !( ( FunctionAnnotation) methodLockCheck ).locked() ) tester.printIfAvailable( value );
        }
        catch( NoSuchMethodException e ) 
        { 
            System.out.println( "[MINIMAL UI][ERROR] Cannot find method to be retrieved. Reflection failed. " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( "[MINIMAL UI][ERROR] Exception during UI testing via reflection: " + e.getMessage() + " Exception: " + e.toString() );
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        System.out.println( "[MINIMAL UI][ERROR] Reflection error. Unable to read annotation!" );
    }
}
```

#### Question

Running `MinimalUI#testUI` results in a `NoSuchMethodException` being thrown, so far I do not understand why. The exact line throwing the exception is `Method possiblyLockedMethod = UITester.class.getMethod( "printIfAvailable" );`.

- Do annotations somehow influence the behavior of `getMethod`? Possibly class declaration is changed somehow?
- Method `printIfAvailable` is declared `public`, so then why is it not found? Do annotations somehow influence the `public` status?
- Both annotations are annoted with `@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )`, is it possible that this prevents the function from being defined as the class is loaded or anything of the sort?

I assume it is something simple I am missing. Currently there were no typos I was able to find, so what is going on there?

Comment: try `getDeclaredMethods()`

Comment: That is not an answer to the question though.

Comment: I would also say this method you're looking for doesn't exist. There exists one with a String parameter, but you're not looking for that ...

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for @Tom. I assume parameter needs to be provided, due to methods being able to be overloaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java getMethod() results in NoSuchMethodException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819886/java-getmethod-results-in-nosuchmethodexception-error)

Comment: Another two possible dupe targets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465407/getdeclaredmethod-doesnt-work-nosuchmethodexception and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944494/java-nosuchmethodexception-with-reflection

Comment: These are easy to find once you know what you are looking for, though. Mostly I found developers running into trouble, because they either declared their method `private` or package-wide. A parameter-issue was not on my mind. In any case - this can be closed.

Comment: Also when you read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) of the method :P. But your question will now also work as a "sign post" for others with similar issue to be pointed into the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `UITester.class.getMethod( "printIfAvailable" )` means that you're trying to get a method called `printIfAvailable` that takes **no** parameters (the `parameterTypes` parameter of `getMethod` is a var-arg).

However, your method is declared with a `String` parameter. You should get it with

```
UITester.class.getMethod( "printIfAvailable", String.class );
```

Comment: Perfect. @Tom also mentioned this, you are both correct. I knew it was something simple I was missing, however I suspected there was something funny going on with the annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem right now is that you're using the `getMethod`-method wrong. You just search for a method without any parameter. If you change it to this `UITester.class.getMethod( "printIfAvailable", String.class );` it will work fine.

JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Returns a {@code Method} object that reflects the specified public
 * member method of the class or interface represented by this
 * {@code Class} object. The {@code name} parameter is a
 * {@code String} specifying the simple name of the desired method. The
 * {@code parameterTypes} parameter is an array of {@code Class}
 * objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared
 * order. If {@code parameterTypes} is {@code null}, it is
 * treated as if it were an empty array.
 * ...
```

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I will upvote yours and mark @ernest_k as accepted, since his answer came first.